# Websphere App Server mutual SSL - obtain CN from client certificate authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication, https, client, websphere

What I have:

- WAS traditional 9.0 with EJB web service;
- webservice client - java application;
- SSL configured for only 9449 port as described here (one way http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-radsecurity3/ws-radsecurity3.html)

I need SSL mutual authentication, so I go to Quality of protection (QoP) settings, and set Client authentication = Required.
Up to this point all works fine.

Problem is that my EJB application needs client certificate's common name to obtain a user ID, which it will use in business logic. And here I failed.
Code snippet (web service side):

```
        MessageContext context = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)context.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST) ;
        System.out.println("!! isSecure " + req.isSecure());

        X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("java.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        if (null != certificates && certificates.length > 0) {
              ...
        } else {
            System.out.println("!! Empty certificates");
        }
```

isSecure returnd true, but I get "Empty certificates" message.

My guess is maybe the reason is in following. When I output the SSL configuration  used on 9449 port, the first line is "com.ibm.ssl.clientAuthenticationSupported = false" while through Admin Console it is set as Required.

```
com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper jsseHelper  = com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper.getInstance();
java.util.Properties props = jsseHelper.getProperties("WebServiceConfigure");
            System.out.println("!!! WebServiceConfigure = " + props.toString());
```

Comment: Do you have cell setup (DMGR and nodes) or stand alone server? In case of cell, you need to make sure that you are setting the QoP settings on the appropriate node where server is is created. If you set it on DMGR, those setting will not apply to other servers.

Comment: I am testing it on standalone, but it will move on to DMGR. I will keep in mind your advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the "direct connect" certificate properties.  This was created to address intermediate (SSL-terminating) proxies (like a web server with plug-in) that issued a certificate different than the ultimate client.  This property is

```
com.ibm.websphere.ssl.direct_connection_peer_certificates
```

You can determine whether you're getting the certificate from direct connect peer or proxied peer via `com.ibm.websphere.webcontainer.is_direct_connection`.

See also: [WAS 9 doc page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rweb_request_attributes.html).

Comment: Thank you, pglezen!

certificates[0].getSubjectDN().getName() returns me CN=xxx, C=YY